# Is there an option to display grid, for programming positions of visible material on screen?

Tags: pdfclown

When doing PDF programming, while adding many visible material on screen (such as text, polygon drawing, picture, colors, border, etc.).

Is there a way to turn on or display grid (can be dots) for measuring the x & y axis positioning?  If so, what objects should I be looking for in PDFClown?

I find it easier to measure the position locations and width/height of objects than spending time calculating the points and making mistake.

Thanks.

P.S. - Also, we don't have to print out the paper and put the plastic grid on it to do the measurement.  Save papers and go green.  ;-)

Comment: How about drawing it? Simply add operations for drawing the grid to the page content during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about drawing a grid? Simply add operations for drawing it to the page content during development.

E.g. you can do it like in [this sample](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfclown0/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfclown0/content/HelloWorldGrid.java) based on the PDF Clown sample [HelloWorldSample.java](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/clown/code/trunk/java/pdfclown.samples.cli/src/org/pdfclown/samples/cli/HelloWorldSample.java):

```
// 1. Instantiate a new PDF file!
/*
 * NOTE: a File object is the low-level (syntactic) representation of a
 * PDF file.
 */
org.pdfclown.files.File file = new org.pdfclown.files.File();

// 2. Get its corresponding document!
/*
 * NOTE: a Document object is the high-level (semantic) representation
 * of a PDF file.
 */
Document document = file.getDocument();

// 3. Insert the contents into the document!
populate(document);

// 3.5 Add a grid to the content
addGrid(document);

// 4. Serialize the PDF file!
file.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "helloWorld-grid.pdf"), SerializationModeEnum.Standard);

file.close();
```

using the helper method `addGrid`:

```
void addGrid(Document document)
{
    for (Page page: document.getPages())
    {
        Dimension2D pageSize = page.getSize();
        PrimitiveComposer composer = new PrimitiveComposer(page);
        composer.beginLocalState();

        composer.setStrokeColor(new DeviceRGBColor(1, 0, 0));
        for (int x = 0; x < pageSize.getWidth(); x+=20)
        {
            composer.startPath(new Point2D.Float(x, 0));
            composer.drawLine(new Point2D.Double(x, pageSize.getHeight()));
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < pageSize.getHeight(); y+=20)
        {
            composer.startPath(new Point2D.Float(0, y));
            composer.drawLine(new Point2D.Double(pageSize.getWidth(), y));
        }

        composer.stroke();

        composer.end();
        composer.flush();
    }
}
```

This results in something like this:

[image: Sample result]